# How to create menu in Python with multiple if statements

Tags: python, function, if-statement, while-loop, menu

I'm trying to create a menu for a POS like system. I have my gift card balances with their numbers and I'm  trying to incorporate this in a menu. In the menu for example, if a user click the number '1', I want the menu to prompt the user for the gift card number in which they will need to enter the correct gift card number (giftnum1). If the user does not click on a valid number or does not enter the correct gift card, I would like the menu to ask the user to click on a valid number or if the user enters the wrong gift card number, I would like for the menu to ask the user to check the gift card number and try again. I am new at this, so I know that most of my menu code is wrong and could be corrected somehow, but I'm not sure how to do this and all other posts relating to this do not make sense with this post.

Here is my code that I have:

```
gift1 = 100
gift2 = 13.50
gift3 = 67.40
giftnum1 = 123456
giftnum2 = 998765
giftnum3 = 456789

print("Here are your current gift cards with the current balances: " + "$" + str(gift1) + " with the gift \ncard number of " + str(giftnum1) + ", $" + str(gift2) + " with a gift card number of " + str(giftnum2) + ", and $" + str(gift3) + " with a gift card number of " + str(giftnum3) + ".")

#making the POS system

def itemmenu():
    print ("Here are the current items with their price. You must choose the correct gift card to go along with the item.")
    print ("1. Nike Shoes ($100)")
    print ("2. Bluetooth Headphones ($67.40)")
    print ("3. Gloves ($13.50)")
    print ("4. Exit")

loop = True

while loop:
    itemmenu()
    buyitems = int(input("Enter the number corresponding to the item that you would like to buy: "))

    if buyitems == 1:
        input("Please enter the correct gift card to buy the Nike Shoes: ")
        if buyitems == giftnum1:
            print("You have successfully entered the correct gift card to buy the Nike Shoes, please follow the directions to be sent a confirmation email.")
            if buyitems != giftnum1:
                print("You have entered an incorrect gift card number.")
    elif buyitems == 2:
        input("Please enter the correct gift card to but the Bluetooth Headphones: ")
        if buyitems == giftnum2:
            print("You have successfully entered the correct gift card to buy the Bluetooth Headphones, please follow the directions to be sent a confirmation email.")
```

Comment: In case of wrong item code or wrong gift card, you again want to display the menu until the user provides a choice 4 i.e. exit?

Comment: And in case user provides correct item no. and gift card no., you want to provide menu again to the user to select another item?

Comment: I've rolled-back your edit adding an answer in your Question. I'm glad you found a solution to your problem. However, an actual answer/solution should **not** be edited into your Question. In general, you should [edit] the Question to *clarify the Question*, but not to include an Answer within the Question. You should create your own Answer with the code you used to solve your problem, then accept it (the system may require a 48 hour delay prior to accepting your own Answer). When you've solved the problem yourself, [answering your own question is encouraged](/help/self-answer).

Answer (score 0):

```
while loop:
    itemmenu()
    buyitems = int(input("Enter the number corresponding to the item that you would like to buy: "))

    if buyitems == 1:
        input("Please enter the correct gift card to buy the Nike Shoes: ")
        if buyitems == giftnum1:
```

You aren't saving the result of the second `input()` call, so `buyitems` is still the same value it was before.

You probably want something like this:

```
if buyitems == 1:
    giftcard = int(input("Please enter the correct gift card to buy the Nike Shoes: "))
    if giftcard == giftnum1:
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tried the solution, but it's going back to the menu where I select what item I want to buy when I enter the correct gift card and not printing that I entered the correct gift card.

Answer (score 0):

Please try below code :

```
gift1 = 100
gift2 = 13.50
gift3 = 67.40
giftnum1 = 123456
giftnum2 = 998765
giftnum3 = 456789

print("Here are your current gift cards with the current balances: " + "$" + str(gift1) + " with the gift \ncard number of " + str(giftnum1) + ", $" + str(gift2) + " with a gift card number of " + str(giftnum2) + ", and $" + str(gift3) + " with a gift card number of " + str(giftnum3) + ".")

#making the POS system

def itemmenu():
    print ("Here are the current items with their price. You must choose the correct gift card to go along with the item.")
    print ("1. Nike Shoes ($100)")
    print ("2. Bluetooth Headphones ($67.40)")
    print ("3. Gloves ($13.50)")
    print ("4. Exit")

loop = True

while loop:
    itemmenu()
    buyitems = int(input("Enter the number corresponding to the item that you would like to buy: "))

    if buyitems == 1:
        while loop:
            giftcardno = int(input("Please enter the correct gift card to buy the Nike Shoes: "))
            if giftcardno == giftnum1:
                print("You have successfully entered the correct gift card to buy the Nike Shoes, please follow the directions to be sent a confirmation email.")
                break
            else:
                print("You have entered an incorrect gift card number. Try again")
    elif buyitems == 2:
        giftcardno = input("Please enter the correct gift card to but the Bluetooth Headphones: ")
        if giftcardno == giftnum2:
            print("You have successfully entered the correct gift card to buy the Bluetooth Headphones, please follow the directions to be sent a confirmation email.")
        else:
            print("You have entered an incorrect gift card number. Try ag")
    else:
        break
```

[image]

Comment: @anthonypollarco this code when entered correct item no. asks for giftcard no. and if it matches with given giftcard no. then it prints message "You have succe..." and asks user to provide choice for next item if user wants so menu is loaded.

Comment: @anthonypollarco Yes it loads the menu again after printing whether it's successful or try again message, I have edited the answer with output. Is this what you required?

Comment: @anthonypollarco Yes it does with the same code, you can take a look at the output where i have entered wrong code then it loads menu again.

Comment: Yes for that you again need to put a while loop: which will ask the user to provide the correct gift card. I have edited the code as well as the output. check it, please.

Answer (score 0):

Hetal Thaker and John Gordon answers are what you are looking for. One issue that may arise though, as you have probably noticed, is that your loop becomes endless even when you select the correct gift card number. To fix that simply set your **loop** variable to False once an item is purchased and it will work.

I have played around with your code a bit and made some transformations using dictionaries and less hard coding. Check it out, it might help in case you have larger data of variables - you can simply put them into the 2 dictionaries and the rest will work on it's own. Note that I did not implement any logic on what happens when the user selects "Exit" as I am not sure what behavior exactly you expect from the program for that. It would also be good to add logic in case the correct gift card is entered but its balance is not enough.

```
gift1_balance = 100
gift2_balance = 13.50
gift3_balance = 67.40
gift1_num = 123456
gift2_num = 998765
gift3_num = 456789

gift_cards = {gift1_num: gift1_balance, gift2_num: gift2_balance, gift3_num: gift3_balance}
merch_to_sell = {"Nike Shoes": [100, 1], "Bluetooth Headphones": [67.40, 2], "Gloves": [13.50, 3]}

print("Here are your current gift cards with the current balances:")
for key, value in gift_cards.items():
    print(f"${value} with the gift card number of {key}")


def item_menu():
    print ("Here are the current items with their price. You must choose the correct gift card to go along with the item.")
    index = 1
    for key, value in merch_to_sell.items():
        print(f"{index}. {key} (${value[0]:.2f})")
        index += 1
    print(f"{index}. Exit")

is_item_bought = False

while not is_item_bought:
    item_menu()

    number_of_item = int(input("Enter the number corresponding to the item that you would like to buy: "))


    current_item = 0
    current_price = 0
    current_index = 0
    get_gift_num = 0

    for k, v in merch_to_sell.items():

        current_item = k
        current_price = v[0]
        current_index = v[1]

        if is_item_bought:
            break

        if number_of_item == current_index:
            get_gift_num = int(input(f"Please enter the correct gift card to buy the {current_item}: "))

            for k, v in gift_cards.items():
                if get_gift_num == k and gift_cards[k] == current_price:
                    print(f"You have successfully entered the correct gift card to buy the {current_item}, please follow the directions to be sent a confirmation email.")
                    is_item_bought = True
                    break

    if not is_item_bought:
        print("You have entered an incorrect gift card number.")
```

If you take this code, you can refactor it and eliminate some unnecessary variables within it and optimize it even further.

Cheers!